# How to reuse the Stub when webservice is relocated to other place?

Tags: jax-ws

My requirement is to relocate the webservice(Jax ws) without building the client side code.
     i want to know is thers any way i can use client code without rebuilding the client.?

thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

The generated client-side stubs for JAX-WS artefacts include constructors for specifying a different URL to that which the stubs were originally generated against. You need to use those constructors when creating a stub instance, instead of using the default constructors.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply,
I am new to jaxws, so if possible can you please explain in detail?

Thaks you...